# ManagedWiFi HostTimeStamp in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, host

I used **ManagedWifi** Wrapper to get some data from SSID.
In this case I tried to get TimeStamp from host, but problem is "I can't recognize those values". I think they are nanoseconds.

[MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Method call is:

```
public ulong hostTimestamp;
/// <summary>
/// The capability value from the beacon packet or probe response.
/// </summary>
```

Example:

```
130815262764460726
130815262774756744
130815262786924765
130815262799248787
130815262813600812
130815262824832832
130815262836064852
130815262846360870
130815262857592890
130815262913908988
```

I want grab **date** from those values in format "yyyyMMdd hh:ss".

Regards,
Nerus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are `Ticks`.
To convert them to `DateTime` do the following:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(130815262836064852);
```

Then to get to the format you want:

```
dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:ss");
```

Comment: I don't know why but I wrote the same code before posting and I head some wrong values (what a dumbass), my bad sorry. 
But those are nanoseconds not Ticks please look at MSDN example
Thx for help.